# Ubuntuのユーザー権限がGUIに反映されない

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud

GCEでUbuntuをXRDPで接続して使う環境を作りました。Ubuntuは17.10です。

新しくSSHでaユーザーを作り、sudoグループに追加しました。
でも、Ubuntuにログインしたら、一般ユーザーのままでした。

`usermod -aG`などで管理者権限つけても、デスクトップのユーザーの情報は一般のままです。

GCE特有のグループを見つけたので、追加させましたがだめでした。

Googleのアカウントのユーザーは、Ubuntuでは管理者権限ついています。
そのユーザーが参加しているグループを確認して追加しました。

google cloud platformで、Ubuntu17.10をインストールして、xrdpでリモートデスクトトップで接続しています。

このために新しく一般ユーザーを作り、sudoのグループに参加させました。

でも、デスクトップにアクセスしてソフトをインストールしようとしたら、「あなたはパーミッションがありません」と言う内容のエラーが出ました。

そのため、ユーザーを管理者権限で使えるようにしました。
GCEで、adminに相当するグループを見つけたので、参加させました。
ちゃんとログインをやり直しましたが、ユーザーの権限が、SSHでは変更できたのに、デスクトップでは変更されません。
デスクトップでもログアウトして、入り直しています。

ユーザー権限を変えたあとにデスクトップのGNOME3に接続後出来なくなり、色々調べている中で、LXDEをインストールしました (VNCでも接続したいこともあったので)。
XRDPでLXDEで、接続できています。でも、ユーザーの権限は、一般のままです。
コマンドでは、ちゃんと管理者権限に変わったことを確認できています。

vino-preferencesなどで、コマンドでウィンドウが開いて設定できることを知っていますが、GCEではポートが使えないので、拒否されてしまいます。
コマンドでウィンドウを開いて設定も出来ないので、困っています。

xrdpで、二つのユーザーをアクセス出来るように設定できたら、Ubuntuでデスクトップでも管理者権限になっている様に切り替えてアクセスできるのですが。

何か解決策が有りましたら、ぜひ、教えてください。

---

- 「コマンドではちゃんと管理者権限に変わった」、という事は以下のように確認しました。
  `su - name` で切り替えました。
  `sudo reboot` を実行して確認しました。
  また、コマンドラインで、＠の左に変更したユーザー名が表示されて確認しました。
- デスクトップのユーザーの情報は一般のまま、というのは以下の画像のような状態です。
  https://gyazo.com/02e0e33d4c943dfd9af506d44bb22ca3

Comment: su - name で切り替えました。　sudo reboot を実行して確認しました。
また、コマンドラインで、＠の左に変更したユーザー名が表示されて確認しました。

Comment: また、SELinuxを知りました。getenforceで確認したところ管理者にselinux-utilsをインストールすることを相談してくださいとメッセージが出ました。

Comment: Google Compute Engineの方で、セキュリティある感じです。Goolgeアカウントでリモート接続は怖いので、追加アカウントでソフトウエアからインストールできるようにしたいです。

Comment: VNCでアクセスしたときも、同じエラー出たので、キャプチャ撮りました。https://gyazo.com/02e0e33d4c943dfd9af506d44bb22ca3

Comment: 情報の追加がある場合は、質問を編集すると読んでもらえます。自分の投稿にコメントしただけだと、あまり他の人の目には触れないです。

Answer (score 3):

Linuxでユーザに対してグループを追加した場合、そのユーザが**所属するグループが増えるだけ**でユーザ自身の権限が直接変わるわけではありません。
(所属しているグループはコマンドで`id`や`groups`と実行すると確認できます）

ファイルやディレクトリ、コマンド毎にパーミッションが設定されており、所属するグループによってそれぞれどのようにアクセス出来るかが決まります。

`usermod -aG sudo`で追加した`sudo`というグループは、恐らく「sudoの実行を許可する」グループではないでしょうか (現に`sudo reboot`は実行できているのですよね？)。

「アプリケーションの追加」で困っているようなので、パッケージマネージャ等をコマンドラインから`sudo`経由で起動するか、sudoのGUIフロントエンド`gksudo`を導入してみてください。

```
$ sudo apt install gksudo
```

---

**追記**
`sudo`コマンドの設定ファイル`/etc/sudoers`を確認すると、`admin`, `sudo`グループに対してsudoを許可するような設定になっていました。私の環境だとデフォルトで作成した一般ユーザはそれぞれ`admin`, `sudo`グループにも所属している状態なので`sudo`コマンドも実行できました。

また、GUIからroot権限が必要なコマンドを実行した場合には`sudo`のGUIフロントエンドがパスワード入力のプロンプトを表示するはずです。Ubuntu(GNOME)環境なら上述の`gksudo`、私が試したKubuntu(KDE)環境だと`kdesudo`がそれに当たります。

デフォルトではインストールされないという話もあるので([参考](https://kledgeb.blogspot.com/2013/10/ubuntu-23-gksugksudo.html))、やはりこちらを確認・インストールしてみてください。

Answer (score 1):

全体として状況がよく解らないのですが、とりあえずは[cubickさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/46723/3054)にある`sudo` を使う方法をお勧めします。

---

#### Polkit

ただ、現在は主要な（特にデスクトップ環境を用意しているような）ディストリビューションでは権限の管理にPolkitが使われていますので、その点を調べたい場合は以下を参考にして下さい。
（初心者の方は読む必要が無いです。とにかく `sudo` が使えるようにして `sudo` を使えばできないことは有りません）

#### ログ

ログはSystemdが取っていると思いますので、`journalctl -u polkit.service` などとすればインストールの不承認を確認できます。

```
# 抜粋
polkitd(authority=local)[868]: Operator of unix-session:3 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-install for system-bus-name::1.258 [gnome-software] (owned by unix-user:***)
```

#### アクションの確認

上で行われた `action` が `org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-install` だと解りますので、これを調べます。

```
$ pkaction -v --action-id org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-install
org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-install:
  description:       Install signed package
  message:           Authentication is required to install software
  vendor:            The PackageKit Project
  vendor_url:        http://www.packagekit.org/
  icon:              package-x-generic
  implicit any:      auth_admin
  implicit inactive: auth_admin
  implicit active:   auth_admin_keep
```

関連するファイルは、

```
/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.packagekit.pkla
/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/org.freedesktop.packagekit.rules
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.packagekit.policy
```

あたりです。

#### 管理者は誰か

誰が `admin` と見なされるかはディストリビューションによって異り、設定ファイルの配置も様々なようですが、例えば `find /etc/polkit-1/ -type f |xargs grep -i admin` のようにすれば、手掛りになります。